# Nested Loop Cuda C

Tags: c, cuda, nested

I have an 1d int-array, and I want to parallelize the 2 for loops.

```
void foo(int *array, int width, int height) {
    for (i = 0 ; i < height ; i++) {
        for (j = 0 ; j < width ; j++) {
            /* do smth */
        }
    }
}
```

Is this the right way to "convert" it to Cuda?

```
__global__ void foo(int *array, int width, int height) {
    unsigned int i = blockIdx.y*blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    unsigned int j = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (i < height && j < width) {
        /* do smth */
    }
}
```

and also, how should I call kernel foo from main?

Comment: The internet is overflowing with  free introductory and tutorial information about CUDA. This question could be easily answered by reading some of it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, that is the correct way to have each thread perform an iteration of that loop.

In order to call kernel `foo`, you are going to need to specify **Grid** and **Block** dimensions and allocate/initialize the Device's memory. It will look something like this.

```
int main(){
    /* Width/Height initialization up to you */
    int width, height;

    /* Device-Level Allocations, etc */
    int *h_arr, *d_arr;
    size_t array_size = width * height * sizeof(int);

    /* Allocate and Initialize Device-level memory */
    cudaMalloc((void **) &d_arr, array_size);
    cudaMemcpy(d_arr, h_arr, array_size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    /* Specify layout of Grid and Blocks */
    dim3 threads_per_block(width, height);
    dim3 blocks_per_dimension(block_x_dim, block_y_dim);

    /* Kernel Invocation */
    foo<<<blocks_per_dimension, threads_per_block>>>(d_arr, width, height);
}
```

The NVidia website has some great resources for learning more on the CUDA platform. I highly recommend reading through some of these--it can help with getting started.

[Intro to CUDA C](http://developer.download.nvidia.com/compute/developertrainingmaterials/presentations/cuda_language/Introduction_to_CUDA_C.pptx)